# Should I have two Controllers when one of the models invariably is dependent of the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, model-view-controller, controller

I have two models `User` and  `Project` with a `one-to-many` association.

An instance (or collection) of `Project` is never "CRUD:ed" by itself, it's always in the context as a property of a `@user`.

Should `Project` still have it's own `Controller` whose every action has to look up which `User` the request is for OR should I add project-related actions in the `UsersController` such as:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show_projects
    @user.projects
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go for having also a controller for the Project models. If you think in RESTful actions then you can think in a call for something like /projects/1 (or other action with an url appending /user like /user/{ID_user}/projects/1) to get project with ID 1 and in the action to process that request checking user permission stuff. Also for example asking for /projects will process a call to get all user's project.

I think that in spite of your Project model having a strong dependency with your User model, doesn't mean that you can't CRUD your Project model. I suppose that somewhere in your app you are going to need to create Projects and that's going to be the place to put CRUD actions for the Project model. Maybe i'm wrong about this (having little information about your app it's difficult to analyse further your problem) but your Project model sounds like a first class entity just like your User model.